# Android action tab listener makes my layout hide

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

In my main activity contains actionbar tablistener, when the tab is swipe or tab then i load the fragment based on the selection, now fragment listview hides below the main activity action bar, 
refer below screen shot
[image]

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/building" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headertext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@drawable/item_background" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Sample list view"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android action tab listener makes my layout hide
`final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(actionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);`